# Get data based on parent table's another child

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, parent-child

I have 3 tables. The relationships are as below:
[ERD of my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu4iJ.jpg)

Student

- has one Parent
- has many Exam

Parent

- belongs to Student

Exam

- belongs to Student

I want to get the parents where country is "Malaysia", and the students that having subject = "English" and grade = "A". How can I write the SQL? I am using Laravel for my project, how to make this in the Eloquent?

Comment: where are grade and subject stored? how did you setup your eloquent relations?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you essentially want all the students who have parents from Malaysia and have a grade of A in English. To get them, I would do something along the lines of:

```
Student::whereHas('parent', function ($query) {
    $query->where('country', 'Malaysia')
})->whereHas('exams', function ($query) {
    $query->where('subject', 'English')->where('grade', 'A')
})->get()
```

The whereHas method (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) uses the relationship to a model to query it. Therefore this is done with the assumption your relationships on the Student model are like so:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Parent::class);
}

public function exams()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Exam::class);
}
```

Include how you've written your relationships on your models in the question next time, it provides a lot more context than an ERD.